# Mysql how to filter results from last CALENDAR month (not last month)

Tags: mysql, sql

I try select data from MySQL for this / last and next calendar month. There are couple of similar posts but none of them address January vs last or December vs next. I know I could do it in PHP around SQL but maybe someone have nice and clean way to address in in SQL. I tried with MOD () but this brings the problem of years. i.e. previous calendar month to avoid 0 in January

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_reservations WHERE ( (MONTH(tbl_reservations.start) = MOD((MONTH(NOW()) +11 ), 12)) AND ( YEAR(tbl_reservations.start) = YEAR(NOW()) ) )
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Coul you provide some data with your Select, its is ahrd to image, whar your problem is

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is pretty easy.  For the last calendar month:

```
where extract(year_month from r.start) = extract(year_month from now() - interval 1 month)
```

You would can use similar logic for next month.

The above is *not* index friendly.  The index friendly version is more cumbersome:

```
where r.start < curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate()))  day and
      r.start >= (curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate()))  day) + interval 1 month
```

This gets the first day of the month by subtracting `(1 - day(curdate()))` days.  Date manipulations and comparisons are then used to get dates for the last month.